# how to compare string to multiple char c++

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm trying to find out whether a string has words in it

```
if( mystring[i] == 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' |)
   // do stuff but it always does stuff no matter that mystring[i] is.
```

is always evaluating to true even if mystring[i] = a space or a period
I tried to use strcmp but I couldn't get that working right. I want it to evaluate true
only if it = a letter.

Comment: what is mystring ? what are words? I suppose these are chars rather than words

Comment: mystring is a string of letters specifically mystring = "ar df" where mystring[0] =a and mystring[5] = f"

Comment: because you should have parenthesis around the pipes. otherwise its only checking for 'a' and then ORing every other character which will always give true because its more than 0. EDIT: parenthesis also wouldn't work because then you would be testing the character to result of a bunch of OR statements. Your best bet is to use `mystring[i] == 'a' || mystring[i] == 'b'`

Comment: how to fix this gasim doesn't the test statement have to be in if(statement) form?

Comment: You can do `if( (mystring[i] == 'a') || (mystring[i] == 'b') || (mystring[i] == 'c') || (mystring[i] == 'd') || (mystring[i] == 'e') )`, but that is repetitive and inflexible to write, and `mystring[i]` is evaluated 5 times at runtime. A simpler form would be `if( (mystring[i] >= 'a') && (mystring[i]) <= 'e') )`, but you are still evaluating `mystring[i]` 2 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot compare multiple values like that.  Use a `switch` statement instead:

```
switch( mystring[i] )
{
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    {
        // do something
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        // do something else
        break;
    }
}
```

In C/C++, if a `case` block does not have a `break` then its execution will continue in the next `case` block.  Thus, all 5 values will execute the same `// do something` code.  Some languages do not do that.

Another option, only because your values are consecutive, is to use this:

```
char ch = mystring[i];
if( (ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'e') )
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: thanks I got it to work using the if statement :D

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code. First, due to precedence, your expression is being evaluated as:

```
(mystring[i] == 'a') | ('b') | ('c') | ('d') | ('e')
```

Second you are using bitwise-or instead of logical-or. What you want to do is have a full condition as each term and switch to logical or:

```
char c = mystring[i];
if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' ...)
```

Finally, if you are planning to check for every lower case letter, the standard library has an `islower` method which can check that:

```
if (islower(mystring[i])
```