# Trouble with setting string by comparing char

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get `char` input from the user, then set a string based off the char that was typed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char direction;
    string printDirection;

    cout << "Inbound or Outbound? (I or O)" << endl;
    cin >> direction;
    if (direction == 'o' || 'O'){
        printDirection = "Outbound";
    }
    else if(direction == 'i' || 'I'){
        printDirection = "Inbound";
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error";
        return 1;
    }
    printDirection;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know of a canonical dup for this, and [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273262/canonical-language-agnostic-question-for-ifvar-x-var-y) seems to indicate that there unfortunately isn't one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare string to multiple char c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358215/how-to-compare-string-to-multiple-char-c)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, adding the dup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (direction == 'o' || 'O')
```

should be

```
if (direction == 'o' || direction == 'O')
```

and the same thing in the other `if` statement.

Comment: Also, `printDirection;` doesn't do anything.  The OP probably meant to use `std::cout << printDirection;` instead.